# Click on imageview appears yellow ring on the picture reclick disappears?

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have imageview when i click on 1 of them yellow ring appears around it when i select another imageview2 the ring goes to the other one and disappears from from imageview 1 with imageview.setbackground(null).
so I want when i reclick on imageview2 with yellow ring the ring disappear like the way i choose another another imageview.

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageView imageView,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4,imageView5,
        imageView6,imageView7,imageView8,imageView9 ;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    imageView6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    imageView7 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    imageView8 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    imageView9 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setEnabled(false);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isSelected(imageView)) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (isSelected(imageView2)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (isSelected(imageView3)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (isSelected(imageView4)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (isSelected(imageView5)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"5",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (isSelected(imageView6)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"6",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (isSelected(imageView7)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"7",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (isSelected(imageView8)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"8",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (isSelected(imageView9)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"9",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

}

private boolean isSelected(ImageView iv){
    Drawable background = iv.getBackground();
    if(background != null)

    return true;
    else 
        return false;

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.highlight);

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageView :
            imageView.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            button.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case R.id.imageView2 :
            imageView2.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);

            break;

        case R.id.imageView3 :
            imageView3.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;


        case R.id.imageView4 :
            imageView4.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView5 :
            imageView5.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView6 :
            imageView6.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView7 :
            imageView7.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView8 :
            imageView8.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView9 :
            imageView9.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            break;



    }
}
```

}

Comment: That doesn't sound so hard. What have your tried? Please share it

Comment: First of all, which language?

Comment: im newbie i have this

Comment: private boolean isSelected(ImageView iv){
        Drawable background = iv.getBackground();
        if(background != null){
            background=null;
        return true;}
        else {
            return false;
        }

Comment: look at my code i putted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there:

All `View`s can have a background, so you can safely change your method `isSelected()` to accept `View`s instead of `ImageView`s:

```
private boolean isSelected(View v){
    return ( v.getBackground() != null );
}
```

Now the first thing to check in `onClick()`is whether the `View` is already selected. In this case, you just set the background to `null`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (isSelected(v)
    {
        v.setBackground(null);
        return;
    }

    Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.highlight);

    switch (v.getId()){

         // this part remains unchanged
    }
}
```